# Importing JSX with ESM Dynamic Imports in Node.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, babeljs, jsx, es6-modules

## Summary of problem

I'm exclusively using ESM in my Node.js project and trying to find a way to dynamically import JSX.

I'm making a custom static site generator for my website and want to render React components to markup with `renderToStaticMarkup()`, but to achieve this, I first need to successfully import the components to then run this method.

Does anyone know a way to dynamically import JSX in ESM Node.js?

I.e., to make `await import("./jsxComponent.js")` work?

## A few things I've tried

### Approach 1: Direct attempt

When I dynamically import the `.js` file containing the component, I receive the error message: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'`. Seems `import()` cannot parse JSX out of the box.

If I change the file extension of the `.js` file to `.jsx`, I unsurprisingly receive the error message `Unknown file extension ".jsx"`.

### Approach 2: Babeling

Back in the CommonJS heyday of Node.js, I'd use `@babel/register`, `@babel/preset-env`, and `@babel/preset-react` in a separate file with its last line invoking `require()` on another `.js` file that, inside itself, would then `require()` the component. I'm not entirely clued up on how each Babel preset or plugin works, but this did the trick back then allowing me to `require()` components to then render them to markup. Unfortunately, this doesn't work when using ESM-only packages in an ESM-only project because the moment I use `@babel/register` my ESM-only packages complain and break.

I've tried using `@babel/core` to transform the file before it's invoked inside `import()`. I've done this by using the `transformFileSync` method, but this created the error message: `Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package '"use strict"`. Inside the options object of `transformFileSync` I used `babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node` as a plugin and `@babel/register`, `@babel/preset-env`, and `@babel/preset-react` as presets.

I've tried also using `@babel/core`'s `transformSync` method by passing in the JSX code directly (rather than just the file path of the JSX-containing file), and this created the error message: `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'import Header from "./src/components/header.js";` (note: there IS a file at `./src/components/header.js` - it is one of the components being imported inside another component.)

### Approach 3: Require

Other approaches online recommend using `require()` instead of `import()`, but as I said, this is an ESM-only project using ESM-only packages and so the error message I receive when trying this is `require is not defined`, as one would expect.

## Code examples

### Approach 1: Direct attempt

`const module = await import("./jsxComponent.js")`

### Approach 2: Babeling

```
const module = await import(
    babelCore.transformFileSync("./jsxComponent.js", {
      presets: [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        [
          "@babel/preset-react",
          {
            runtime: "automatic",
          },
        ],
      ],
      plugins: ["dynamic-import-node"],
    }).code
  );
```

(Let me know if you want me to post any more code examples from my tests with Babel).

### Approach 3: Require

`const module = require("./jsxComponent.js")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to import JSX in my ESM-only project by:

1. Installing `@node-loader/babel` ([see GitHub repo](https://github.com/node-loader/node-loader-babel))
2. Installing `@babel/core` and `@babel/preset-react`
3. Creating `babel.config.js` in my root directory with the following setup:

```
export default {
  presets: [
    [
      "@babel/preset-react",
      {
        runtime: "automatic",
      },
    ],
  ],
};
```

4. Then running my node build script with the node loader set as an experimental loader: `node --experimental-loader @node-loader/babel ./lib/build.js`

I was then able to successfully use `const component = await import("./jsxComponent.js")` in my node build scripts and pass the component to reactDOMServer's `renderToStaticMarkup(component())` method by invoking it as a function.